# How can I fix a computer that blue screens before Windows starts?

Tags: windows-7, windows, bsod, dell-inspiron

I have a Dell Inspiron running Windows 7 that keeps getting blue screens of death. At first, the computer slowed down so much it was unusable. After some time, it wouldn't even load Windows anymore; the machine just started going straight to a BSOD after the starting Windows logo. I have tried loading the reset disc, but it just takes me to a loading lobby and never advances. I don't need the files on the computer, but I do need the machine for school. What can I do?

Comment: Edit your post to include the specific Model of your notebook please.

Answer (score 0):

Run a diagnostic on the memory and hard drive.

Start at the Second post in [this thread](http://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Lockups-Freezes-Hangs/How-to-test-RAM-and-HDD-Hard-Drive/td-p/301638).

.

I can give better Dell diagnostic software links and instructions as soon as I know your specific model number.

Answer (score 0):

If your computer blue screens than windows has already started. Not succesfully, but you are already starting it when it fails. This can have two reasons:

1. A problem with the windows installation, or
2. A hardware problem.

If it is a problem with the windows installation then you can boot from other media. I am guessing that you already tried this since you mentioned a reset disc.

That leaves a hardware problem. An unidentified one. At this stage and with data you want on disk it is prudent to remove that disk from the computer. Try it in a different desktop or via ESATA or external FireWire or USB case. Copy your data. if possible.  Also check the disks SMART attributes.

If it is the disk which is failing then buy a new one. Reinstall windows and copy data back from your backups.  If it is something else which is failing then do the usualu diagnostics for that (e.g. fan working, not overheating, thermal paste replaced, DIMM reseated, memory test runs succesful, ...)